# XSLT: How to apply for-loop?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Could you please tell me how to apply a for-loop in XSLT?

Here is my [live code at xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLL/2).

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <h1>A new version of xsltransform.net is released!</h1>
    <p>We have added the following new features:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a license (thank you Michael Kay!)</li>
        <li>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</li>
        <li>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</li>
        <li>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO. Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF</li>
        <li>Added some links to useful XSLT sites</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="'ss'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="inline-array">
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:param name="array" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='inline-array']/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="$inline-array">
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**expected output**

```
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
<h1>C</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, your `inline-array` variable contains a "Result Tree Fragment", so to access the nodes within it, you will need to make use of the "node-set" extension function.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:variable name="inline-array">
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($inline-array)/Item">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note that you can also use the `document` function, as you have included in you sample, although I believe XSLTransform.net doesn't allow the use of the document function, so you can't test it there, but this should work run locally

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="array" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='inline-array']/*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="inline-array">
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$array">
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </h1>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add another `for-each` for the `item`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="'ss'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="inline-array">
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:param name="array" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='inline-array']/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="$inline-array">
        <xsl:for-each select="Item"> //<--Added this line
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>     
        </xsl:for-each>  //<--Added this line too
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><h1>A</h1><h1>B</h1><h1>C</h1>
```

[**Demo**](http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLL/4)

Comment: Your stylesheet declares version 1.0, but you're testing it with an XSLT 2.0 processor. **It will not work in XSLT 1.0**: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLL/5 --- That's not to mention that a single `<xsl:for-each select="$inline-array/Item">` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating and accessing an `<xsl:variable>` would be using some kind of a "data-island" in your XSLT file.

**One major advantage of this approach is that you don't have to deal with RTFs(Resulting-tree-fragments) and so you can query the XML as you like.**

Its creation is simply done by defining a namespace for it (here: `xmlns:items="http://ite.ms"`) and then accessing it via the `document('')/xsl:stylesheet/namespace:...` XPath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:items="http://ite.ms" >

    <!-- kind of "data-island" -->
    <items:Items>    
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>   
    </items:Items>    

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/items:Items/Item">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></h1><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I prefer this way because IMHO it's the cleanest approach of embedding XML data in an XSLT.

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
<h1>C</h1>
```